# Class function not working

Tags: magento2, helper, class

I tried to call the class using construct method.

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper

{

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 * */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList
 * */
protected $_directorylist;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress
 * */
protected $remoteAddress;
/**
 * constructor
 * \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
 * \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $_directorylist
 * */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directorylist,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
) 
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_directorylist = $directorylist;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
}

/**
 * @param $config_path 
 * @return config_value
 * */
public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}

/**
 *  
 * @return media_path
 * */
public function getMediaPath()
{
    return $this->_directorylist->getPath('media');
}

/**
 *  
 * @return string
 * */
public static function getMagentoFormKey() 
{
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    return $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
}

//function to get the current user ip
public static function get_user_ip() 
{
    return $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart 
    //$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    //return $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress')->getRemoteAddress();
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
}

}
```

I got this error `Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php:95`

Can anyone please help to me for this?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is not even `95 line` of code, please make sure you added the whole code to your question.

Comment: agree with @Dominic Xigen remove the `static` keyword in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove static parts from public static

That's about it. Everything else looks good.